# How to Create Local Sqlite Data Table on Xamarin and Check it with Device Monitor?

Tags: xamarin-studio, system.data.sqlite

Have My DatabaseHelper Class

```
public class DatabaseHelper : SQLiteOpenHelper
```

And Methods inside like

```
  private static readonly String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
                    + TABLE_USERS + "(" + USER_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + USER_PASS
                    + " TEXT," + USER_NAME + " TEXT," + USER_SURNAME + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";
```

Here my DatabaseHelper class Constructure and onCreate() onUpgrade() methods

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context): base(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION){}

            public override void OnCreate (SQLiteDatabase db)
            {
                db.ExecSQL (CREATE_USER_TABLE);
                db.ExecSQL (CREATE_RECORDS_TABLE);
                db.ExecSQL (CREATE_COMPANY_TABLE);
                db.ExecSQL (CREATE_COMPANY_LIST_TABLE);
                db.ExecSQL (CREATE_NOTIUPLIST_TABLE);
                db.ExecSQL (CREATE_NOTIFICATION_DELETE_LIST_TABLE);
                db.ExecSQL (CREATE_MYNOTIFICATION_LIST_TABLE);
            }
 public override void OnUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException ();
            }
```

And I call it from mainActivity

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper (Application.Context);
```

Looking through **Android Device Monitor** data-->data-->my package name--> but dont see any created table Where I am missing to do something?
I have also added SQLite -net PCL package

Comment: Are you using an emulator or an actual device to test on?

Comment: to see sqlite database tables I guess I have to use emulator that I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't view your database on an actual device, unless that device is rooted. All of the examples you are seeing that are explaining how to find your database on the file system are assuming you're using an emulator.

Comment: That very clear sir I know it. Would you help me to create my tables on Sqlite database on Xamarin, thank you.